# Remove fabricjs object in loop

Tags: fabricjs

I want to remove only objects having type `textbox`, but while using for loop its not removing all may be because object length change and index shift. Any suggestion ?

Here is my code

```
texBoxItems = canvas.getObjects();

for(var i=0; i<texBoxItems.length; i++ ){

if(texBoxItems[i].get('type') == "textbox"){
    if(texBoxItems[i].active == false){
        canvas.setActiveObject(texBoxItems[i]);
         canvas.remove(texBoxItems[i]);
    }
    else{
         canvas.remove(texBoxItems[i]);
    } 
  } 
}
```

Comment: you want to remove all the textbox objects?

Comment: Yes, all textbox objects

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var objects = canvas.getObjects('textbox');
canvas.remove(...objects);
```

Get all the objects of type [getObjects('textbox')](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Canvas.html#getObjects) then remove objects using [remove()](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Canvas.html#remove).

***DEMO***

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
var text1 = new fabric.Textbox('Text',{
 left:10,top:20
})
var text2 = new fabric.Textbox('Text',{
 left:50,top:50
})
var rect = new fabric.Rect({
 left:150,top:150,width:100,height:100
})
canvas.add(text1,text2,rect);

function remove(){
 var objects = canvas.getObjects('textbox');
 canvas.remove(...objects);
}
```

```css
canvas{
 border:1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/kangax/fabric.js/master/dist/fabric.js"></script>
<button id="aligntext" onclick="remove()">remove</button> 
<canvas id="c" width="400" height="400" style="border:1px solid #000000;"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative method is to start from the length (minus one) of the objects up to zero:

```
texBoxItems = canvas.getObjects();

for(var i = texBoxItems.length - 1; i>= 0; i-- ){ // This is the only change I've made to your code

if(texBoxItems[i].get('type') == "textbox"){
  if(texBoxItems[i].active == false){
    canvas.setActiveObject(texBoxItems[i]);
      canvas.remove(texBoxItems[i]);
    }
    else{
      canvas.remove(texBoxItems[i]);
    } 
  } 
}
```